# Is it possible to call Timer ISR when we want it to execute.?

Tags: pic, timer

I am using PIC32 and I am doing a timer example. I am using the example of Timer1 provided in microchip documents. My understanding with the timers is when our main program start, timer also start with given timing. So its ISR start functioning with the given timing. Is it possible to start the ISR when we want. For example, if a button is pressed then timer ISR should be called.

```
#include <plib.h>
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCPLL, FPLLMUL = MUL_20
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_1, FPBDIV = DIV_8
#pragma config POSCMOD = OFF, FWDTEN = OFF

#define FOSC 80000000
#define PB_DIV 8
#define PRESCALE 256
#define TICKS_PER_SEC 4
#define T1_TICK_RATE (FOSC/PB_DIV/PRESCALE/TICKS_PER_SEC)
int main(void)
{

  OpenTimer1(T1_ON | T1_SOURCE_INT | T1_PS_1_256, T1_TICK_RATE);
  ConfigIntTimer1(T1_INT_ON | T1_INT_PRIOR_3);
  INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt();
  while(1)
  {
    //... do something useful here ...
  };
 }
 void __ISR(_TIMER_1_VECTOR, ipl3) Timer1Handler(void)
{
  mT1ClearIntFlag();
}
```

How to call `__ISR(_TIMER_1_VECTOR, ipl3) Timer1Handler(void)` when we want in our program.

Comment: While you can do this in a number of different ways, as detailed in  the answers below, its seems strange that you would want or need to. What problem are you hoping to solve by calling your timer ISR function?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish what you want in two ways. The second way should be considered "best practice".

First way: create a function to be called by your ISR and call that same function in other parts of your code. Depending on how __ISR() is defined, Timer1Handler() could be called directly in main(), but I'm not 100% sure about it.

```
void myFunction()
{
  // ... do what you want as Timer1Handler ...
}

void __ISR(_TIMER_1_VECTOR, ipl3) Timer1Handler()
{
  myFunction();
}

int main()
{
  // ... main application calling myFunction() ...
}
```

Second way: you have said "if a button is pressed, the ISR should be called". Then what you should do here is create a different ISR for an external interrupt regarding that button. This could call that same function as the Timer ISR.

```
void myFunction()
{
  // ... do what you want ...
}

void __ISR(_TIMER_1_VECTOR, ipl3) Timer1Handler()
{
  myFunction();
}

void __ISR(_EXTERNAL_0_VECTOR, ipl3) External0Handler()
{
  myFunction();
}

int main()
{
  // ... do what you want ...
}
```

Final thoughts: as a general rule, interrupts handlers shouldn't do much "work". You want them to have as short execution as possible. In my projects, ISR normally just set some logical *volatile* variables checked in other code parts or alter some GPIOs. Make sure to keep your handlers simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstanding the purpose of the timer ISR.

The ISR is executed by hardware when the timer rolls over. This will continue to happen every time the timer rolls over.

You can disable the timer and then enable it when a button press happens but only hardware should be calling the interrupt directly. Don't forget to clear the TMR register before enabling the timer.

Answer (score 1):

In PIC32, software can generate any interrupt. I.e., if for whatever reason you want to execute the ISR all you need to do is to set the flag for this interrupt. I don't know whether a function (similar to 'mT1ClearIntFlag()' ) is available but setting/clearing bits is really quite trivial - look into the header file for your device, you'll likely find a `#define _T1IF...` somewhere in it. After that, setting the flag is as easy as coding '_T1IF = 1;'.